# getView and Beacon(Estimote) problem in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, estimote

My idea is to get the title from a beacon and based on that title send me an appropriate Layout. But suddenly it wont recognize my inquiry. Like String == String won't work.

Here is the code of a View, if you guys need something else I will post or we can make a skype session just to teach me this one.

```java
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ProximityContent content = nearbyContent.get(position);
    String beacon = content.getTitle();

    if (beacon == "one") {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            assert inflater != null;

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tester_beacon_i, parent, false);
        }
    } else if (beacon == "two") {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            assert inflater != null;

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tester_beacon_ii, parent, false);
        }
    } else if (beacon == "three") {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            assert inflater != null;

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tester_beacon_iii, parent, false);
        }
    } else {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            assert inflater != null;

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tester_beacon_iv, parent, false);
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

So every time my app starts, I get only `tester_beacon_iv` layout, 4 times instead of getting all 4 layouts on all 4 beacons together.

P.S. I am using Estimote beacons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `==` on two strings in Java, you're not actually comparing the strings themselves. You will need to use `.equals(String)` instead. This is because `==` actually compares the two objects' references, not their values.

`string1.equals(string2)` compares the two strings based on the actual characters in the strings.

In your case, the first three beacons will never match, so you'll aways get layout #4. You'll need to write:

```
if (beacon.equals("one")) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I did this and now instead of 4 times going to layout_iv, it is going to layout_1 than layout_4 than layout_1 again and layout_4 again...

Comment: It worked when I deleted if (convertView == null) and did .equals, thank you very much my friend.

Answer (score 0):

`==` isn't guaranteed to work on Strings in Java. For your particular case, I'd recommend using a `switch` statement.

```java
switch (beacon) {
case "one":
    // ...
    break;
case "two":
    // ...
    break;
case "three":
    // ...
    break;
default:
    // When none of them match ...
    break;
}
```

Comment: I did this and now instead of 4 times going to layout_iv, it is going to layout_1 than layout_4 than layout_1 again and layout_4 again... Same as .equal...

Comment: @NikolaMilojic Did you try it with your "It worked when I deleted if (convertView == null)" fix?